# How to ensure signing of test-jars in package phase?

Tags: maven-2

I have a multi-module project where the parent POM specifies (in a profile) the configuration and use of the maven-jarsigner-plugin to sign the jars that the project produces.

```
<profile>
    <id>sign</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>sign-jars</id>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <keystore>/tmp/certificates.ks</keystore>
                    <alias>jarsign</alias>
                    <storepass>password</storepass>
                    <keypass>password</keypass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Some of the sub-modules in the project additionally use the maven-jar-plugin to produce a test jar:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm observing that when the signing profile is enabled (e.g., `mvn -Psign install`) Maven executes goals in the following order:

- jar:jar
- jarsigner:sign
- jar:test-jar
- install:install

This results in an unsigned test-jar (both in `target/` and in the local repository) which then causes java security problems when a subsequent project attempts to use that test-jar.

Is there a way to ensure that jar:jar and jar:test-jar execute prior to the jarsigner:sign?

Answer (score 1):

Move your `test-jar` execution to the `prepare-package` phase, then it will be there by the time jarsigner gets to go.

Alternatively, specify the signing profile in the same POM as the test-jar.

I have a similar situation with the assembly plugin, where if assembly and jarsigner are in the same POM, the order is fine, but if jarsigner is in the parent POM, then the order is bad (Maven 2.2.1).

Comment: For now, I bound the signing to the install phase.  It sounds like this sort of problem is very common in Maven and it isn't clear if the Maven developer community really believes it is a bug or not... see for example http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2258 and the many related linked issues.  Certainly, it does not appear to have been addressed systematically :-/